# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm in the middle of upgrading from `netcore2.2` to `netcore3.1`

I have a line that calls to `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` which results in the below

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions'.'

I know this is related to an on-going issue (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1869), but that doesn't help me resolve the issue.

Is there a known work-around?

Comment: ... have you updated the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package to the latest version?

Comment: I'd udpated everything, turns out it was a test mocking out `IHostingEnvironment` :/

Comment: Please post that as a self-answer once the waiting period has elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd udpated everything, turns out it was a test mocking out IHostingEnvironment