# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment with xunit

Tags: c#, resharper, xunit

I'm trying to use resharper xunit testing.

I setup a test class like this

```
public class CropLossLandingPageServiceTest
{
    private readonly IWPCropLossRequestService cropLossRequestService;

    public CropLossLandingPageServiceTest(IWPCropLossRequestService cropLossRequestService)
    {
        this.cropLossRequestService = cropLossRequestService;
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Banner Message Test")]
    public async void GetBannerMessageTest()
    {
        var result = this.cropLossRequestService.GetBannerMessage();
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
}
```

Get this error

> System.TypeLoadException Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtensionWithDebugInfo'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.8.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.    at
> xxx.WUOM.Data.Models.WFOrderMgmtContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder
> optionsBuilder)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()

Do I have to setup dependency injection in the test class? I should not have to change GetBannerMessageTest().

related link: [Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68922808/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-ihostingenviron/70585671#70585671)

Comment: With that minimum of code it is hard to say anything in detail... but unless you have very good reasons, I would not use a DI container for the unit tests. You better keep the code constructing your system under test close to the tests itself (either within the test or with a factory method).
Can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.